# A nation is using its citizens as a distributed computing network to solve some kind of problem. What kind of problem is it trying to solve?

Tags: society, science-in-society, population, computers

Long story short, the government of The People's Representative Democratic Federated Republic of Southeast Countryistan has its citizens fill out a couple of forms per day, each with some kind of question on them. These questions are being used as a very weird sort of [distributed computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_computing), in that each citizen is the processor and each form is the operation that processor is intended to complete.

Note that **these sets of questions are not *surveys*** - they aren't looking for the opinions of the citizens, nor are they looking for feedback from the citizens. They are simply using a portion of the populace's time and thought processes to solve some kind of problem that an ordinary computer cannot solve. **The nature of that problem is is for Stack Exchange to determine**, since I, for the life of me, figure out what such a problem could be.

Why? Why would the government do this? This is a pretty inefficient way of processing information; there must be some reason they're going with people filling out forms rather than simply using a computer.

**All acceptable answers will cite some kind of problem (how you define "problem" can whatever you want it to be) that cannot be solved by (a) a single human, (b) a group of humans smaller than the population of an entire country, or (c) a computer.**

Comment: This looks to be a question about the motivation of entities within your world. Such questions are entirely up to you as the worldbuilder.

Comment: @sphennings It's not about motivation; I know what their motivation is, which is to solve some kind of problem by using people as computing nodes. What I don't know is what that type of problem is, because I don't know what type of problem could be solved only by a large number of people. I will edit the question to clarify, but it's not about the motivation of entities within my world.

Comment: You should probably read the Hitchhikers guide to the Galaxy, humans are used as organic computer there.

Comment: @L.Dutch Yeah, they already have their answer: 42.

Comment: "Who will be eliminated on next week's bachelor." Technically a self-fulfilling prophecy I guess.

Comment: I recommend The Drummers from Diamond Age as a wonderful prior art.

Comment: Your question needs clarification. What is typically on a form? How are they produced? How are they processed after being marked by a human?

Comment: @Dan All of those are based off of what the question is. For instance, with sdfgeoff's answer, the form would likely be a paper slip similar to the answer section of a standardized test, featuring (a) basic identifying information regarding the formfiller and (b) an ethics question with a multiple choice answer, with the forms probably being processed by machine. But, as I said, it varies by question.

Comment: It cannot be anything regarding actually computing something, because of [Amdahl's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl's_law). Using millions of extremely very slow processors with slow communications is a non-starter.

Comment: @AlexP yeah it will take a while.. but you could solve travelling salesman in the mean time ? ask them when the package arrived.. In a year or so you'll find some optimal path :d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are establishing a moral and ethical baseline for the next generation of AI.

---

Your nation isn't using computers to do the task, so traditional math and logic is out. Instead we have to find a topic that humans are great at, and can figure out in a few moments what would take a computer hours (it at all).

One thing humans are fast at is making moral decisions. One thing humans are not good at are making unbaised ones. So by utilizing the entire population of the country, they hope that the resulting training for the AI will be unbiased insofar as its a representation of the populations total bais.

Of course, this does blur the line between opinion survey vs calculation, but any calculation is effectively 'what do you think the answer is'.

So, your nation is developing an AI, and every week they compare the populations 'computation' against the AI's

Comment: People tend to use non-binding referenda as an opportunity to vent their frustrations or to exercise their sense of humor. The results of non-binding referenda are not to be taken seriously.

Comment: @AlexP Is explicitly establishing the moral framework for your future AI Overlord really the equivalent of a non-binding referendum, though?

Comment: @Jedediah Not at all. In a non-binding referendum you have the *possibility* that someone might answer dishonestly for their own amusement. In generating your New Robot Overlords, you have the *certainty* that people will cheat for their future benefit.

Comment: @Cadence Absolutely.  Which, come to think of it, might be a surprisingly effective way to educate an AI.

Answer (score 1):

- It is kind of a universal help forum. Only, instead of relying on someone to come along to answer a question, specific people are tasked with giving an answer.
- It is a similar to the game trivial pursuit - just on a scale of nation-vs-nation.
- It measures how information is distributed among the population. These results ultimately can be used to effect changes to reduce friction and delays in publishing information. Also useful for countering misinformation before it gets out of hand.
- The places in which the questions are asked and answered are packed with sensors evaluating a person's (mental) well-being. The idea is, people are bad at self evaluation, better give them a task to concentrate on and gather "objective" sensor data.
- The answers are used in drafting new laws and rules, imparting a large part of the population with the feeling of being involved in important decisions.

It is probably all of the above and more.

Answer (score 1):

The severly broken down harmonics analysis is performed to derive the tides pattern across all harbors of the nation.
Especially if no sort of computing has been invented and your planet has more satelites then just Moon, this actually might be an interesting approach to solve it.
Veritaserum did a video on this few weeks back, take a look at it https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=IgF3OX8nT0w in short Lord Kelvin said “fudge it that is too much repetive math that needs to be done, I will make a computer instead.” But if you failed to make the computer?

Answer (score 1):

Someone came up with a brilliant idea to improve the world, but it might be unethical. Philosophers and ethicists were deeply divided on the subject, so the government decided to try AI. The AI subcommittee on the budget committee couldn't pry enough money out of the main committee to be able to reach a definitive answer. Then someone thought of an ironic way to seek an answer.

The question is:

Would it be ethically permissible for the government to require all citizens answer at least two questions per day on Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

They're brute-forcing some NP hard problem. Possibly Traveling Salesman. I have no idea why. This is an absurdly expensive proposition, even from the standpoint of GDP, given that it must negatively impact the economy in general. And, likely, this is either an extremely inefficient method, or one that just won't work at all.

I struggle to come up with a more polite term, but possibly they're all some sort of idiot savants, for whom this is a compulsion without reason.